# Getting maven to start jetty (Tapestry Tutorial)

Tags: java, maven-2, jetty, tapestry

I'm trying to work through the Tapestry tutorial.

I think I got everything set up right and so far so good but I get to the [part](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5/tutorial1/first.html) where the tut rather glibly states:

> Change into the newly created
>   directory, and execute the command:
>
> `mvn jetty:run`
>
> Again, the first time, there's a
>   dizzying number of downloads, but
>   before you know it, the Jetty servlet
>   container is up and running.

I wish! that only results in the following error.

> The plugin
>   'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jetty-plugin'
>   does not exist or no valid version
>   could be found

I have maven-2.2.0, Jetty-5.1.9

The only thing I did different to what the tutorial stated was I used *archetype:generate* instead of *archetype:create* as *create* failed and noted it was deprecated and suggested *generate* instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to missing maven-jetty-plugin in your pom.xml file :

Add the following dependency in pom:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.1</version>
      </plugin>
```

now mvn clean install and then jetty run it will work

Answer (score 0):

It can't find it because it's not in the default org.apache.maven.plugins or org.codehaus.mojo locations where Maven looks by default to map the prefix to an artifactId. You have two choices, define the plugin in your pom, or add the jetty group as a pluginGroup in your settings.xml

Comment: Thanks Brain. I will check this one out as well. While @xorza's answer does indeed work, it does not actualy solve the problem.

Comment: This is what you want if jetty isn't otherwise configured in your pom:
<profile>
  ...
  <pluginGroups>
    <pluginGroup>org.mortbay.jetty</pluginGroup>
  </pluginGroups>
</profile>

See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin